# Apache HttpClient and other classes are unresolved in my Android app

Tags: android, apache

I've added to my android-gradle project this:

```
# app/build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company1.android.my_app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}


//..............

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

all of these are unresolved:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
```

A peace of my code, both are unresolved:

```
  val client = DefaultHttpClient()
  val post = HttpPost("fdsfd")
```

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated so you should use Urlconnection manager for newest API version

Comment: @Madhu, where is that said?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html read this link

Comment: Use [HTTPUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead.

Comment: Or use [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) instead, it's very easy to port over.